# How to write general get methods for a class?

Tags: python, oop, methods, args

recently I started using oop in python. I would like to write a general get or set method for the initiated attributes. For example, there is the class Song with several attributes and a corresponding get method. I would like to avoid the multiple if statements. With just two attributes it does not matter, but if there are >5 attributes the code would be difficult to read. Is it possible to use a string in args to get the value from **init** whithout defining all possible cases?

```
class Song(object):

    def __init__(self,title,prod):
        self.title = title
        self.prod = prod

    def getParam(self,*args):
        retPar = dict()
        if 'title' in args: 
            print(self.title)
            retPar['title'] = self.title
        if 'prod' in args:
            print(self.prod)
            retPar['prod'] = self.prod
        return(retPar)
```

I am not sure, if this is possible, because I could not find anything. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this. Why do you need a method at all?

Comment: `return {attr: getattr(self, attr) for attr in args}`…?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: to provide a function for colleagues who are not familiar with the python syntax, such that they do not have to access the the attritubes directly. For plotting and such things.

Comment: *"I would like to write a general get or set method for the initiated attributes"* - why? This isn't Java, either access them directly or use a `@property`.

Comment: thank you @deceze, could you post that as answer? I did not know the getattr() function or  Thank you very much!

Comment: Why would anyone not familiar with even the most basic Python syntax write Python? How is `attrs = song.getParam('title', 'prod'); attrs['title']` any better or easier than `song.title`?

Comment: because python is not necessarily taught and the dot syntax is confusing for people who have basic knowledge in matlab.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> provide a function for colleagues who are not familiar with the python syntax, such that they do not have to access the the attritubes directly. For plotting and such things
>
> because python is not necessarily taught and the dot syntax is confusing for people who have basic knowledge in matlab

I'd argue that this can easily be taught and you shouldn't bend over backwards for something so simple… but assuming this is really what you want, this looks like a much better idea:

```
class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, title, prod):
        self.title = title
        self.prod = prod
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

song = Song('Foo', 'Bar')
print song['title']
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__ and https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr.